# How do I eliminate data that falls within a range of other data in the same query?

Tags: sql-server, range

I have a query that returns results that describe a numeric range, with some of these data falling within the range of other data returned in the same query. How can I easily eliminate those?

I have the following data:

```
Code    Start     End
-----   -------   -------
abc       1         1
abc       2         2
abc       3         8
abc       4         4
abc       5         5
xyz       1         1
xyz       2         5
xyz       3         3
```

In this case, where code is "abc", there are two rows: start=4,end=4 and start=5,end=5. But preceding them is a row where start=3,end=8. So both of those rows should not be returned in my result set.

I can do with with a temp table, cursor, etc. But I'd like to know if there's an elegant way to do this within the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a WHERE NOT EXISTS() clause.

The EXISTS() function would be to check for another row where the `Start` is less than or equal to my `Start` and the `End` is greater than or equal to my `End`.

There are no exact duplicate rows in your sample data, but if it's possible for them to exist in your real data, you will have to consider what you want to do with those as well.